# how can you tell which version of an Ubuntu package includes a particular patch?

Tags: package-management

If a system requires a patch that I found upstream, how can I tell which version of an Ubuntu package contains the commit that includes that patch?

Comment: You can't really, as the versions in Ubuntu may not match Upstream Latest.  This is also an **extremely broad** question because short of examining source code of packages yourself, this isn't really answerable.  Is there an example of what exactly you're referring to here?

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about serious security breaches with known CVE number, then [https://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-security/cve/](https://people.canonical.com/%7Eubuntu-security/cve/) is good place to find package versions.

Other possible way is to read Changelog file of the exact package:

1. Visit https://packages.ubuntu.com
2. Search for package name, choose needed release
3. Click on *Ubuntu Resources* → *Ubuntu Changelog* to download changelog.

Going down to the commit is theoretically possible by switching to *Source* package and reading its source code or commit history.

---

Example `avahi-daemon` with known CVE-2017-6519:

- for known CVE - CVE-2017-6519 - [https://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-security/cve/2017/CVE-2017-6519.html](https://people.canonical.com/%7Eubuntu-security/cve/2017/CVE-2017-6519.html)
- this CVE is mentioned in [Changelog](http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/a/avahi/avahi_0.6.32%7Erc+dfsg-1ubuntu2.3/changelog)
- on source level you can find it in Debian Salsa (not usually, sometimes in LaunchPad) - [using search](https://salsa.debian.org/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=CVE-2017-6519&group_id=2692&project_id=8500&scope=&search_code=true&snippets=false&repository_ref=debian%2Fmaster&nav_source=navbar)